# No xor gcc intrinsics for ARM NEON

Tags: gcc, arm, intrinsics, neon

I could not find any intrinsics for a simple xor operation.

See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html

Are there really no way to use NEON instructions for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The instructions are called eor (Exclusive OR).

Comment: They're even clearly labeled on the page the questioner linked: "6.53.3.78 Logical operations (exclusive OR)"